# Celery worker receives unregeistered task from celerybeat run by systemd

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, systemd, django-celery, celerybeat

On my staging server I had my celery worker(4.3.0) up and running with celery beat as daemons via systemd with RabbitMQ as broker. Everything was alright for few weeks just to the one moment 4 days ago when there was some sort of connection error between celery and amqp through kombu. `[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer after started`

I wasn't paying much of an attention to the server logs, since the project is in WiP stage, however when I tried to deploy newest version of the code, I realized that something is wrong with the worker.

I googled for the issue and that's what popped out: 
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4867

The easy solution was to downgrade celery to 4.1.1 and wait till fix in future stable releases.

I removed celery, amqp, billiard and kombu from my venv, installed celery.4.1.1, which installed above packages in appropriate versions.

Atm services of celery and celerybeat are active, celerybeat sends the tasks to the celery worker, however celery logs shows me error message (please see error code of celery after downgrade). It is weird, because I haven't changed anything in task declarations or my settings ( which may be the issue here).

The weirdest thing is that if I shut down systemd services and run them with the commend: 
`celery -A celery_cfg:app worker -B --loglevel=DEBUG`

All current tasks are being proceed as the past ones. So the celery and celerybeat configs as they are seems to be working.

Few pointed approaches I tried:
1) Made sure to import all modules without relatives imports.
2) In the past encountered issue with missing packages in venv --> they are up to date
3) Rebooted celery/celerybeat/gunicorn/systemd/rabbitmq and server itself
4) Double checked the paths in systemd services (however maybe I am debugging this to long and I just cant see the typo or something)
5) Tried with developing version `4.4.0rc2`, (celery worker won't stand up)
6) Installed apps contains all required apps

Error message after downgrade of celery version

```
    `2019-06-16 19:35:00,092: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'apps.mailing.tasks.execute_sending_system_mail'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/user/apps/venv/loans/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 557, in on_task_received
   strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'apps.mailing.tasks.execute_sending_system_mail'
```

Celery Service Systemd Code

```
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=<user>
Group=<user>
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/<user>/apps/loans
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
 -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
 --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
 --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
 -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
```

Celery Beat Service Systemd Code

```
Description=Celery Beat Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/apps/loans
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} beat  \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Conf file for variables

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

CELERY_BIN="/home/user/apps/venv/loans/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="celery_cfg:app"

CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

CELERYD_OPTS=""

CELERYD_PID_FILE="/home/user/apps/pids/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/home/user/apps/logs/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/home/user/apps/pids/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/home/user/apps/logs/celery/beat.log"
```

celery_cfg file

```
app = Celery('loans_apps')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.set_default()

# <====CELERY BEAT PERIODIC TASKS ====>
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'execute_sending_system_mail': {
        'task': 'apps.mailing.tasks.execute_sending_system_mail',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),
        'args': (),
    },
}


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

minor cut of settings containing celery cfg variables

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost//',
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

I know I can try setting celery and celerybeat without systemd, however I treat this as the last resort solution. I'd like to keep the conf as it was, even though I've no clue what's is wrong up there.

EDIT
By the mistake and guided by my friend I just found out, that both celery and celerybeat services seems to be working fine on user root, which is obviously not the solution but narrows down the number of possible flaws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be rude to leave the question unanswered, even though the answer comes from me, here it is:

If someone will ever encounter such issue, after following  step pointed by me above, try to check for the permissions of directories which celery and celerybeat uses - You might have created them with root permissions, which may ends up with mentioned issue. Good luck to everyone in the future !